# How does C++ handle double moves?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, if I have a function:

```
struct my_type {
   void add(some_type st) {
       values_.emplace_back(
           std::move(st)
       );
   }
   vector<some_type> values_;
};
```

And I call the member:

```
int main() {
    my_type mt;
    some_type st;
    mt.add(std::move(st));
}
```

I've moved st into the argument for add, which them just turns right around and moves it into a container it's managing.

This turns up quite a lot where I've got wrapper around some underlying container.

Does the C++ language allow/require some optimization of this "double move" pattern?  Or should I be writing separate lvalue and rvalue add functions?

Comment: Yes, an implementation can and will elliminate the move if the function is inlined. But I would probably make `add` a variadic template with universal references and perfect forwarding, because I can, or just in case `some_type` grows some constructors while I'm on vacation.

Comment: How would having explicit move constructors affect it?

Comment: @n.m I would not unless this is generic code.  99/100 types will be fine with by-value methods here, and if the type is fixed we know if it is the 1/100.

Comment: You could have the add function accept by perfect forwarding

Comment: An inlined function that does nothing but perfectly forwards its arguments to another function should not have any runtime costs, regardless of what exactly it forwards.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont do you know how many constructors some_type has? How many will it acquire during program development?Is it copyable? Movable? Will it always remain such? Do you want to care?

Comment: Possibly relevant question: [Why are there two overloads for vector::push_back?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28130531/580083).

Comment: `void add(some_type&& st)` is an alternative, and disallow implicit copy and so force `mt.add(some_type(st))`.

Answer (score 1):

A move is a cast to an rvalue reference.

What that does depends on what function or ctor you pass it to.

In your case, it depend on what `some_type` does when you construct an instance from a `some_type&&`.

That is literaly arbitrary code that you haven't included.

If `some_type` is written with a simple and efficient move ctor, and it doesn't leak its identity, under as-if the intermediate instance could be eliminated.  On the other hand, if `some_type` leaks identity or does other similar and/or bad things, the intermediate object may have to practically exist.

As an example, a `std::vector` as `some_type` could probably be eliminated; and if not, you wouldn't care, as a move is 3 pointers copied and zeroed.  A type that prints its address when copied to std err, probably not.

There is currently nothing similar to elision that allows lifetime merging despite side effects.  There have been some proposals along that direction, but I am unaware of any getting far (which mostly is evidence of my ignorance, not evidence of lack of existence), and I doubt they cover this case.

If you don't know what elision is, you should go learn; you need new vocabulary before you can discuss this issue practically.  Talking about this issue in C++ without understanding C++ elision is like discussing e^(ipi)+1=0 with someone who doesn't know what multiplication is.  Possible, but long winded.

Comment: I know what a move is, and I know what type elision is, I was asking specifically about anything in C++ that would allow/require the double move to be eliminated, as when copying the compiler is allowed to elide copies even when there are are side effects in the copy constructor.

Comment: @gct So, see punultimate paragraph